# Set a interval of numbers in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I set a interval in `TextField`? I want it accepting only numbers in the range `1-100`...

Here is my widget:

```
TextField(
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3)
          ],
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: '',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hello, have you looked into the [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) widget? it might be better for this. Otherwise you could add another inputFormatter that validates that the number is between 1 and 100.

Comment: Hi! its for a search, must be a TextField... How i do other inputFormatter with that filter? Can u help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own input formatter that can limit the range of numbers like this:

```
    class LimitRangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  LimitRangeTextInputFormatter(this.min, this.max, {this.defaultIfEmpty = false}) : assert(min < max);

  final int min;
  final int max;
  final bool defaultIfEmpty;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    int? value = int.tryParse(newValue.text);
    String? enforceValue;
    if(value != null) {
      if (value < min) {
        enforceValue = min.toString();
      } else if (value > max) {
        enforceValue = max.toString();
      }
    }
    else{
      if(defaultIfEmpty) {
        enforceValue = min.toString();
      }
    }
    // filtered interval result
    if(enforceValue != null){
      return TextEditingValue(text: enforceValue, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: enforceValue.length));
    }
    // value that fit requirements
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Then add it to your inputFormatters:

```
inputFormatters: [
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
    LimitRangeTextInputFormatter(1, 100),
],
```

With this if the user types a number greater than 100 the text field will change it back to 100.

You can also use `LimitRangeTextInputFormatter(1, 100, defaultIfEmpty:true)` to force the empty value.