# To limit the values ​that I am getting numbers from user into textFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
TextFormField(
 inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')),
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
              ],
          maxLength: 2,
          controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
```

I want to prevent the user from entering a number greater than 12 in the TextFormField. It can only write numbers between 1-12(including 12).

Comment: Idk for such small range of number you may consider using sliders. (ofc I don't know what are you doing so it might be not fitting)

Comment: i updated the original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050167/set-a-interval-of-numbers-in-textfield with TextSelection based on Ivo answer, have a look and let us knows ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this custom formatter:

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
      if (newValue.text == '') return newValue;
      final i = int.tryParse(newValue.text);
      if (i == null) return oldValue;
      if (i > 12) return newValue.copyWith(text: '12', selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 2));
      return newValue;
    })
  ],
  maxLength: 2,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

try This one its one help to you

```
TextField(
  controller: textEditingEventController,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
  ],
  onChanged: (val) {
    if (int.parse(((val.isEmpty) ? '00' : (val))) > 60) {
      textEditingEventController.text = '12';
    }
    textEditingEventController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: textEditingEventController.text,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(
            offset: textEditingEventController.value.selection.baseOffset),
      ),
    );
    textEditingEventController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: textEditingEventController.text.length));
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a custom formatter, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050167/set-a-interval-of-numbers-in-textfield)

```
     class LimitRangeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  LimitRangeTextInputFormatter(this.min, this.max, {this.defaultIfEmpty = false}) : assert(min < max);

  final int min;
  final int max;
  final bool defaultIfEmpty;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    int? value = int.tryParse(newValue.text);
    String? enforceValue;
    if(value != null) {
      if (value < min) {
        enforceValue = min.toString();
      } else if (value > max) {
        enforceValue = max.toString();
      }
    }
    else{
      if(defaultIfEmpty) {
        enforceValue = min.toString();
      }
    }
    // filtered interval result
    if(enforceValue != null){
      return TextEditingValue(text: enforceValue, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: enforceValue.length));
    }
    // value that fit requirements
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

You can also achieve like this, not sure it is the best way but the idea it to use a dialog to prevent user and force the previous value if it does not fit requirements you want.

```
onChanged: (String value) async {
  if (value.isEmpty || int.tryParse(value) > 12) {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Error '),
          content: const Text('must be defined and lower than 12.'),
          actions:  <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    // force old value
    controller.text = oldValue;
    return;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use regex like this one
`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^([1][0-2]?|[1-9])$'))`

But it is better to use onChange in text field and create function to check if value is > 12

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextFormField as

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            counterText: "",
          ),
          controller: textEditingController,
          maxLength: 2,
        )
```

And TextEditing Controller

```
final textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    EditingController();
  }

  EditingController() {
    textEditingController.addListener(() {
      var value =textEditingController.text;
       if (int.parse(value) > 12) {
         textEditingController.clear();
       }
    });
  }
```